# vba selenium waitDisplay method not working

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

Who can tell me why the method of Selenium `WebDriver.WaitDisplayed` is not working in my code below?

I can share other code if needed?

```
Set a = webdriber.FindElementsByClass("search-global-typeahead__collapsed-search-button")
a.Item(1).WaitDisplayed(True).Click ' operation timed out after -1ms. Run-time err'21'
a.Item(1).Click ' gives an error
```

I added code below; without successful result

```
a.Item(1).WaitDisplayed(True, 100).Until(a.Item(1).IsDisplayed,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess to start with the most obvious, does it still cause an error after fixing the typo in the 'webdriber' identifier? I'm guessing your declaration is spelled 'webdriver'.